# Delete duplicates records working from table not working

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

I am trying to delete duplicates from Redshift database

```
WITH CTE AS
         (SELECT org_country_code,dest_country_code,postcode,
                 zone,kg,value,carrier,version,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                     partition BY org_country_code, dest_country_code, postcode,
                         zone, kg, value,carrier, version
                     ORDER BY org_country_code, dest_country_code,
                         postcode, zone, kg, value,carrier, version) rnum
          FROM dhl_gb.dhl_gb_td_exp_ww_l10kg_transformed
             ) DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rnum<>1
```

What is wrong in this? Any help appreciated?

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: @GMB,I dont a single primary key as such .`org_country_code, dest_country_code, postcode, zone, kg, value,carrier, version ` together can be considered together for udentifying unique records

Comment: Can you please try selecting the cte? It will tell you the is row number performed on correct columns?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal, Select is working correctly. But only delete is having issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can modify the `CTE`. How about this?:

```
WITH CTE AS
         (SELECT org_country_code,dest_country_code,postcode,
                 zone,kg,value,carrier,version,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                     partition BY org_country_code, dest_country_code, postcode,
                         zone, kg, value,carrier, version
                     ORDER BY org_country_code, dest_country_code,
                         postcode, zone, kg, value,carrier, version) rnum
          FROM dhl_gb.dhl_gb_td_exp_ww_l10kg_transformed
             ), 

CTE2 AS SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rnum = 1

SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**  This does not work in Redshift.

With no PK, you will need to use the [ctid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT CTID as rid,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                     partition BY org_country_code, dest_country_code, postcode,
                         zone, kg, value,carrier, version
                     ) rnum
    FROM dhl_gb.dhl_gb_td_exp_ww_l10kg_transformed
) 
DELETE FROM dhl_gb.dhl_gb_td_exp_ww_l10kg_transformed
 WHERE CTID in (select rid from CTE where rnum > 1);
```

Comment: getting an error `[42703][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "ctid" does not exist in dhl_gb_td_exp_ww_l10kg_transformed;`.

Comment: Sorry--I did not see the `redshift` tag.  Isn't deleting on redshift not recommended?  I would do this as a CTAS `select distinct *` into a temp table, truncate the original table, and then load it from the temp table.